# In a GNU C macro envSet(name), what does (void) "" name mean?

Tags: c, gcc, macros, c-preprocessor

I came across this syntax today and couldn't work out what it meant:

```
// Uses the GNU C statement expression extension
#define envSet(name) ({ \
static int initialised; \
static bool set; \
(void) "" name; \
if (!initialised || !g_cacheEnv) { \
    const char *value = getenv(name); \
    set = value != NULL; \
    initialised = true; \
} \
set; \
})
```

The specific line I cannot understand is:

```
(void) "" name; \
```

Could somebody please shed some light on this?

Comment: I don't think it is an extension...

Comment: @EugeneSh. the specific line I was referring to isn't, but the context it was used in is :)

Comment: Well, then the title is probably misleading a bit..

Comment: @OMGtechy, Where's that macro from? (out of curiosity)

Comment: @ilkkachu I came across it as part of my work :)

Comment: Perhaps a clearer alternative is `(void) "Must be a string literal: " name;` which documents the intent, and should generate a self-documenting error message as well. A good compiler should also optimize away the string in the binary.

Comment: @chi in the end I just added a comment saying exactly what it did

Answer (score 76, accepted):

It looks like a way to statically ensure that `name` is a string literal and not some other type.

If you do `(void)"" "hello";` then it is a valid C expression.

But if you do something like `(void)"" 1;` then you get a syntax error.

Comment: It worth mentioning that prepending by `(void)` is to silence the "unused" (or whatever) warning.

Comment: And perhaps also worth mentioning that this uses the fact that adjacent string literals are concatenated by the preprocessor, so it won't work if the right-hand side (`name`) isn't a string literal. The cast is applied to the result of the concatenation, not to `""` by itself. Edit: oh, didn't see the other answer. Heh.

Comment: Technically, string literal concatenation happens _after_ the preprocessor but _before_ everything else. It gets a translation phase all to itself (number 6).  The most obvious way this is visible is that they are not merged in `-E` output, and you can also observe it with various macro tricks (macro expansion is phase 4).

Comment: My comment on @ milleniumbug’s answer applies here too.

Comment: @zwol: how is the translation phase relevant to this answer? Or do you just mention that for those who are interested?

Comment: @PJTraill: I think zwol was just trying to clarify the ever-so-slight inaccuracy in unwind's comment.

Comment: @PJTraill I mainly mention it for the sake of people who might be confused to see string literals _not_ getting merged in `-E` output.

Answer (score 45):

Two consecutive string literals are concatenated. Presumably it's checking whether `name` is a string literal. If it isn't, the compiler will report an error.

`(void)` cast will supress warnings like "statement with no effect".

Comment: thank you, I accepted the other because it provided an example of how the PP would handle it :)

Comment: @OMGtechy in general, you are free to accept any answer, without giving an excuse. Just saying...:)

Comment: It looks as though it fails on `envSet(+1)`. One would moreover expect `getenv(name)` to cause the compiler to validate `name` unless using suicidally weak checking options, which makes me wonder if this is meant for some peculiar environment, or just an odd exercise.

Comment: @PJTraill `getenv(name)` will hopefully (assuming warnings enabled) check whether it's convertible to `const char*`, and the fragment in question will check whether it's a string literal. These two complement each other. Now, what's the point of it, I'm just as lost as you are.

Comment: @machine_1 I just want to be polite when someone has taken the time to answer my question

Comment: @milleniumbug: The first time a particular expansion of the macro is executed, it will call "getenv". If it is executed again, it will not call "getenv" again but simply yield whatever result it yielded the first time.  That will be a useful optimization provided that neither the environment nor the passed-in string changes. It would be a bad idea if the passed-in string could change between invocations, however. String literals are generally guaranteed not to change between invocations, and represent the most vast majority of the use cases for which a function like this would be appropriate.

Comment: @supercat: I think you have it worked out: an optimisation with a check that it is _fairly_ safe – maybe you could work that up into an answer! Or you could extend one of the existing answers. But I do wonder if the (author + compile) time saved by not providing comments (presuming the questioner hid nothing) was worth more than the time spent by those deciphering it — especially now it has appeared on SO!

Comment: @PJTraill: In cases where machine-generated code would need to compute something once and cache the result, a useful approach would be to put a relative call instruction in-line whose target would compute the value in question and then replace the call instruction with a "load" of the proper value.  Such an approach would eliminate the need for the "if" check on all repetitions after the first, but in the absence of language support there's no way to do such a thing safely when using modern compilers.

Comment: @PJTraill: The `envSet(+1)` use would escape the concatenation check, but would fail the routine check on the call to `getenv()` — as you're aware.  What the check still provides protection against is `const char *ptr = "SOME_NAME"; envSet(ptr);` — passing a character pointer that is not a string literal.  This would pass `getenv()`, but doesn't pass the string concatenation check.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: More to the point, `char name[10] = "SOME_NAME"; envSet(name);`.  Since a const-qualifier on a pointer's target type implies that the pointer won't be used to modify the target (at least not without a cast), but doesn't promise that the target won't change via other means, the `char[10]` could be passed to code expecting a `const*` without even needing a cast.

Comment: Great answer! I think it is better than the accepted answer because it explains what the expression actually does.

Answer (score 7):

Looking at the code, I believe the purpose is to have it call `getenv` the first time it is called, cache the result, and then after that use the cached result without having to call `getenv` anymore.  If `getenv` is used with a string literal, then all subsequent calls will ask for the same environment variable; if nothing could change that environment variable they would consequently return the same result.  If the code were given a pointer to a string that subsequently changed, the cached result would likely not be correct for the new string, so the purpose of the "" trick is to ensure that can't happen.

Because every string literal that might be used would need to have its own static variable associated with it, the indicated code snippet cannot sensibly be made into a function.  On the other hand, the amount of code needed for each repetition does seem a bit much.  Further, if the same variable is tested at more than one place in the code, each could end up with its own set of variables and environment-checking code.

Depending upon how the function will be used, it may end up being much faster than code which needs to test an environmental variable every time it's called, and it may be usable from within a function that is called within a loop without advance setup (if client code called an "advance setup" function, the name lookup should be done there, eliminating the need to check within the loop to see if the lookup had been done).

Comment: This is indeed the context in which it is used, and why :)

Comment: Thanks for providing the most thorough and illuminating answer so far. I can’t help thinking that …`static const char * const name_const = name; /* Require a compile-time constant */ const char * value = getenv (name_const);`… would have achieved the same a lot more clearly! Or am I missing something?

Comment: @PJTraill: Given `char foo[16];`, I think that approach would accept `(const char*)foo`, even though the contents of `foo` could get changed arbitrarily between queries.

Comment: I think you are right, though a sensible compiler sensibly used should warn that you are casting away `const`. And wilful C users can always cast themselves into the pit where the worm gnaws and the fire burns forever.

Comment: @PJTraill: In the absence of cast, assigning the address of `foo` would be a constraint violation.  The cast, however, will generally suppress any diagonstic.  Also, if there were a `union` with both a `const`-qualified and non-qualified member of otherwise identical types, I think writing via the non-qualified member and reading via the qualified members would be defined behavior but would not be expected to produce any diagnostic.

Comment: You’re right: at least one of the three compilers I regularly use (MSVS, C for AIX, “DEC” C) warns against casting **away** `const`, but you are casting **to** `const`.

Comment: @PJTraill: In C, the normal meaning of a "const" pointer is "pointer that can not be used to change something", rather than "pointer to thing that will not be changed via any means".  Thinking about it, I don't think the cast would even be needed.

Comment: @supercat: You beat me to it; it occurred to me too that the cast was unnecessary.